# Name and location of profile management tool in Websphere Application Server 7?

Tags: websphere-7, ibm-was

IIRC whenever I use to install WAS on my Windows PC it used to create short cuts to desktop of profile management tool. This time it wasn't created, please tell me the name and location of that batch file (in WAS) from where I can create the similar short cut again by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the UI part but in case you want to create it from commands you can do this -

```
manageprofiles.bat -create -profileName AnyAppSrv -profilePath %WAS_HOME%\profiles\AnyAppSrv -templatePath %WAS_HOME%\profileTemplates\default -serverName server1 -cellName AnyAppSrvNode1Cell -nodeName AnyAppSrvNode1 -hostName localhost -enableAdminSecurity false
```

Note: Path may differ which you have to set on your own.

Answer (score 3):

The Profile Management Tool (pmt) is available here:

```
C:\PATH_to_WebSphere_AppServer\bin\ProfileManagement\pmt.bat
```

be aware that in WebSphere v7, there is no pmt tool in 64-bit WebSphere version. So, if you installed 64-bit WebSphere you will not have that short cut.

For 64-bit you will need to use `manageprofiles.bat` command line tool.